# Dependencies between async tasks

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I call my async method several times, ones for each unit

```
var tasks = otherData.Select(async unit =>
  await OneUnitProcessor.ProcessOneUnitAsync(
    var1,
    authenticationResponse,
    unit,
    reservation: new Reservation()
  )
);

await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

This is my async method:

```
 public static async Task ProcessOneUnitAsync(string var1, ServiceResponse authenticationResponse, ChannelManagerJsonHolder unit,IReservation reservation, CookieCollection cookieCollection = null)
    {
 List<Task<HttpResponseMessage>> tasksDeleteReservations = reservation.DeleteReservations(allLinksToDelete, authenticationResponse, unit);


 var occupiedPricesItems = OccupationPriceGetter.GetOccupiedPeriodsWithPrices(fiksniTecaj,   authenticationResponse, unit, cookieCollection);


 tasksOccupied = allOccupationsToInsert.Select(async price => await Api.CalendarPrices.SendRequestAsync(authenticationResponse, unit, price, unavailable: true));

 await Task.WhenAll(tasksOccupied.Union(tasksDeleteReservations));
 }
```

Basically there are tasks which delete reservations(`tasksDeleteReservations`) and  tasks that insert reservations (`tasksOccupied`). This solution is not good for me because I want achieve solution that all "old" reservations are deleted before inserting new one (all `tasksDeleteReservations` tasks are finished before `tasksOccupied`)

One solution would be to have two awaits inside my async method, but I don't think it is good solution two have multiple awaits (control will return to the caller and I think program will exit before all other tasks (related to inserting reservations) are finished. 
Other solution would be to block on deleting before contiuning to inserting, but this is probably not async code anymore.
 **How to achieve asynchronicity and order of execution in situation like this?**

EDIT1: Here is the code that calls tasks which process all units;

```
   private async Task ProcessAllUnits(string var1, IEnumerable<ChannelManagerJsonHolder> otherData, ServiceResponse authenticationResponse)
    {

        try
        {
            var tasks = otherData.Select(async unit => await OneUnitProcessor.ProcessOneUnitAsync(fiksniTecaj, authenticationResponse, unit, reservation: new Reservation()));
            await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
        }
        catch (AggregateException ex)
        {
            foreach (var innerException in ex.InnerExceptions)
            {
                new FileLogger().Log("Unit level exception:" + innerException.Message, ChannelManager.Core.Utilities.Logging.LogLevel.Error);
            }

        }

    }
```

ProcessAllUnits is called by some other method. Here is the code of that method:

```
  private async Task LoginAndProcessAllUnits(string var1, UserModel     oneGroupedCMJsonHolder,IAuthentication authentication)
 {
 var task = ProcessAllUnits(fiksniTecaj, otherData, authenticationResponse);
                await task;
   }
```

This is top level method:

```
public  void ProcessAllUsersAsync(List<ChannelManagerJsonHolder>    CMJsonHolder, string var1)
        {
 var tasks = new List<Task>();
              foreach (var group in groupedCMJsonHolder)
             {
                  var task = LoginAndProcessAllUnits(fiksniTecaj, group, new    Authentication());
                   tasks.Add(task);
            }
              Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
```

}

Comment: If you need to wait for the Deletes then you have to wait.....
You could use ContinueWith but I think that's essentially the same as await.

I see no problem awaiting the deletes if the process requires it.

Comment: For someone who would ask: Why I want to delete before inserting. Because inserting will fail if new reservation is defined in same or "similar"" period like old reservation. So I want to delete them all (one by one; async network calls) , than insert reservations one by one(again async calls over network)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with having multiple `await`s in one method. In fact, that's why you're using `await` in the first place, really - to manage the state machine and continuations for you.

Yes, control will return to the caller. But the point is, if you're using `await`, you need to use `await` all the way - the behaviour you're describing will only occur when your `await` chain is broken by some method that doesn't `await` on some asynchronous method. That's where your problem is, not the `async` methods that `await` multiple times.

Comment: No, I'm using asnyc await all the way.(I think :) )

Comment: @Vlado Yeah, in that case, `await`s will appear synchronous as if they were blocking calls (with a bit of reentrancy). Just remember that the tasks start when you call the methods, not when you `await` them - so if you want to delete the reservations before creating the new one, you need to `await` the delete task before executing the next task.

Comment: I made edit with code that I think is asncy all the way.

Comment: @Vlado In the top-level method, you're no longer using await - so if something expects that everything finished by the time `ProcessAllUsersAsync` exits, you might have an issue. If it is truly top-level, it's fine - but there really isn't a reason to ever use `void` with an async method; the only reason it's even allowed is that event handlers *can't* return `Task` (they must always return `void`). If you're using it as a fire-and-forget task, you're mostly fine (though you should add proper error-handling).

Comment: Real top level method is the the main method(console app), but main method can't have async keyword I think.

Comment: @Vlado True, but that doesn't mean you can't make it :P This really depends on what you're trying to do, though - if you want to run something as a background task with respect to the console app, you might be fine with just remembering the `Task` and only synchronizing when necessary. If you want it to be synchronous, just make a `MainAsync` method and call that from the actual `Main` with `MainAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();` - and now you can use `await` in `MainAsync` as usual.

Comment: Everywhere else I'm using Task.WaitAll, but in ProcessAllUsersAsync method which returns void I'm using Task.WaitAll, so I think it will wait before exiting app.

Answer (score 2):

All you need is two awaits on those task collections. Control does return to the caller but the task is not completed. If the task were completed by using await what good would the feature be?! It would amount to what `return` does.

The task that you start with `async unit => ...` will also complete only when then `OneUnitProcessor.ProcessOneUnitAsync...` task is done.

And `await Task.WhenAll(tasks);` completed when all these tasks are done.

`await` is for serializing execution of tasks.

Comment: Code is worth more than 1000 ordinary words. You want to say to write something like this: Remove last line and write this:await Task.WhenAll(tasksOccupied);await Task.WhenAll(tasksDeleteReservations)?

Comment: Like that, but you need to await before starting the inserts. Otherwise, the deletes might still be running. await does not start anything, it waits for things that run already.

Comment: If I understand you code will go like this. One unit will be started processing(when it comes to first await then it will return to caller to start executing another unit). Unit tasks are still in pending state. Eventually program will come to second await. Control will again be returned to the caller, but the point you want to say is that task (oneUnitProceesor) will be completed when it see's last brace of the method. So the solution for ordering the executions is to have mutiple awaits inside one async method. Did I understand you correctly?

Comment: Sorry ;await Task.WhenAll(tasksDeleteReservations) should come first

Comment: `Control will again be returned to the caller` that only happens once. Then, the incoming call is done forever and the async method runs independently like a thread. If the task returned to the caller is awaited that joins the caller and the async method back together. So when you say await F(); this means that caller and callee will run concurrently for a very short time, then join back. Hope that helps to understand what's going on.; So use multiple awaits to delay task completion, yes.